# Chi-square test for two vectors with very similar values

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I have two vectors with two levels:

vector 1:`[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 Levels: 0 1`

vector 2:`[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 Levels: 0 1`

As you can see these two vectors are very similar, the only difference is that level 0 exist in vector 2 (once) but not in vector 1. I tried to use the chi-square test to compare the distribution using R, however, I got an error message saying that:`Error in stats::chisq.test(x, y) :  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels`

I tried to use fisher exact test but it gave me a p value = 1, which I don't believe is reasonable. Is there something wrong when I implement these tests? Or should switch to a more appropriate test for this task? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: "which I don't believe is reasonable" Why do you think so?

Comment: Each vector represent the presence or absence of a certain molecule in patient, 1 is presence and 0 is absence. I don't think it is reasonable because if two vectors are almost the same the association shall be significant, correct?

Comment: Perhaps the most appropriate approach is simply report the proportion of responses, either in the table as whole, or within each, say *Vector 1*.  And then maybe state that due to the distribution of values, a hypothesis test would not be meaningful. `Vector1 = factor(rep(1, 65), levels=c(0,1)); Vector2 = factor(c(rep(1,64), 0)); Table = table(Vector1, Vector2); Table; prop.table(Table); prop.table(Table, margin=1)`

Comment: A good way to look at data like this is to ask what the likely outcome would be if all the components of the two vectors combined were randomly re-assigned to the vectors (which is precisely what you are doing when you randomize the patients into two groups, for instance).  In your case, *one of the vectors will necessarily have one zero* and all the other components will be ones.  Thus, it is *certain* that this apparent difference in the vectors will be present, no matter what!  That's why the correct p-value is $1.$

Answer (score 0):

The null hypothesis for the Fisher test is Group1 = Group2. The alternative test is Group1 $\neq$ Group2
A high p value means you "fail to reject" the Null hypothesis.

Therefore accept the null hypothesis (taking all of the assumptions and warnings into account) *Group1 matches Group2*